# Chat suspension message is unreadable in rooms parented to a beta site

Tags: bug, chat, design, chat-ban

I was conducting some experiments on my sockpuppet, which included handing out a chat suspension to... well, myself, on another account. I discovered, however, that the "your account has been suspended" message that shows up is unreadable:

[image]

Highlighting the text, I can see what it says:

> your account has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 59 minutes.

But otherwise, only the two words "your account" are visible, leaving users possibly confused about why they can't send any messages and why there's a link to their chat profile showing up instead of the textbox.